# how do I match up the values in order to compare them

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I need to get the date difference between two time of two different rows.  I have tried to manipulate the Ids of this table but found a dead end.

The table looks like this:

```
ID      TimeIn       TimeOut     EmpId
 1      8.30am       12.30pm      usr1
 2      1.30pm       5.30pm       usr1
```

I need to get the time difference between `TimeOut` of the first row and `Timein` of the second row.

The expected output should be like this:

`EmpId        LunchTime`
`usr1            1:00`

`1:00` equivalent to 1 hour.

Comment: depending if your database supports it, use the LAG function.

Comment: @Randy, LAG function? never heard of it. I am currently using Sql Server.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: what is the data type of `TimeIn` and `TimeOut` ?

Comment: @KhurramAli, Well my original query is a little bit more complicated that this. I have tried nested select use the <> function to differentiate the Ids.

Comment: some examples here match closely http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/lead-and-lag-functions-in-sql-server-2012.html

Comment: @KhurramAli, The datatype of TimeIn and TimeOut is DateTime

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: @ChloeBenjiman Edit Your Question and add Your Output Sample

Comment: @KhurramAli, Kindly check out my edited question and output sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what you are really asking is, "how do I match up the values in order to compare them". The comparison is trivial once you have both values, but matching up pairs of rows is less straightforward. Check out this article for an almost exact step by step on how to solve something like that: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/solving-complex-t-sql-problems,-step-by-step/

Answer (score 0):

Following is my code and test it in MYSQL for your reference.

```
//EMP table content like below
id  TimeIn              TimeOut             EmpId
1   2015-03-21 09:00:00 2015-03-21 12:30:00 usr1
2   2015-03-21 13:30:00 2015-03-21 17:30:00 usr1
3   2015-03-21 08:00:00 2015-03-21 13:30:00 usr2
4   2015-03-21 14:00:00 2015-03-21 16:00:00 usr2
// find every empId TimeOut of first row and TimeIn of second row
SELECT id,TimeOut ,EmpId,
(select c.TimeIn from EMP  c where c.EmpId = a.EmpId and c.id > a.id limit 1) as 'TimeIn'
 from EMP a
//result as below
1   2015-03-21 12:30:00 usr1    2015-03-21 13:30:00
2   2015-03-21 17:30:00 usr1    NULL
3   2015-03-21 13:30:00 usr2    2015-03-21 14:00:00
4   2015-03-21 16:00:00 usr2    NULL
//find the timediff between TimeIn and TimeOut
select id,EmpId,timediff(TimeIn,TimeOut) as diff from 
(
  SELECT id,TimeOut ,EmpId,
  (select c.TimeIn from EMP  c where c.EmpId = a.EmpId and c.id > a.id limit 1) as 'TimeIn'
  from EMP a
) as tmp
// result as below
id  EmpId   diff
1   usr1    01:00:00
2   usr1    NULL
3   usr2    00:30:00
4   usr2    NULL
```

Hope this can help you.